# How can i write multiline command in execcommand in jenkins while Publish over ssh?

Tags: ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In below script i want to add one more command "iisreset" in execcommand parameter:

```
        steps {
            echo "${DBServer}"
            echo "Deploying Report Build Service"
            sshPublisher(
                publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(
                        configName: "${PortalServer}", 
                        transfers: [sshTransfer(
                            execTimeout: 120000,
                            execCommand: "xcopy /s/e/y/i C:\\Artifacts\\build-${BUILD_NUMBER}\\ReportBuildService C:\\ABC\\ReportBuildService",
                            makeEmptyDirs: true,
                            patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
                            remoteDirectory: "Artifacts/build-${BUILD_NUMBER}/ReportBuildService", 
                            removePrefix: "/ReportBuildAndReleaseService/bin//${params.Configuration}", 
                            sourceFiles: "/ReportBuildAndReleaseService/bin//${params.Configuration}//**")],
                        verbose: true)
                    ]
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use `;`:

```
execCommand: "xcopy /s/e/y/i C:\\Artifacts\\build-${BUILD_NUMBER}\\ReportBuildService C:\\ABC\\ReportBuildService ; #second command"
```